# Chart.js + Angular 5 - Destroy() multiple dynamic charts created through *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, chart.js

I have created multiple dynamic charts by *ngFor loop and its working. But I want to destroy all the charts before creating them second time. is there any way to achieve it. I want to destroy() the charts before creating new one but due to unknown number of charts every time i am enable to achieve it.

my chartjs.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { pieceLabel } from 'chart.piecelabel.js';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chartjs',
    templateUrl: './chartjs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chartjs.component.css']
})
export class ChartjsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    jsons: any;
    NumberOfSystems: Number;
    charts = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.jsons = data
            this.NumberOfSystems = this.jsons.data[0][1].systems.length
            this.createChartsData()
        });
    }

    createChartsData() {
        var array = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.NumberOfSystems; i++) {
            var pie = {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Disks", "Mgmt", "Hardware", "FC", "Vols&Pols"],
                    datasets: [{
                        backgroundColor: ["#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000"],
                        data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: { display: false },
                    animations: true,
                    tooltips: { enabled: true },
                    legend: { display: true }
                }
            };
            array.push(pie);
        }

        this.createCharts(array);
    }

    createCharts(pieData) {
        if (canvas0) {
            this.canvas0.destroy();
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < this.NumberOfSystems; j++) {
            let htmlRef = this.elementRef.nativeElement.select(`canvas` + j);
            console.log(htmlRef);
            var tempChart = new Chart(htmlRef, pieData[j]);
            this.charts.push(tempChart);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the chartjs.component.html:

```
<div>
    <canvas *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index" id="canvas{{i}}"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: When do you want to destroy the chart?

Comment: I have an select filter on my component. on changing data changes. I am editing my question and the destroy() should be before creating as per docs. at start of function.

Comment: You can create a public variable named `array:any;` and in `createChartData()` you can define it blank initially. so whenever that function is called it will be blanked first like `this.array=[];`

Comment: As per docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy.

Comment: I can destroy single chart like this this.myChart0.destroy(); or but dont know how to do this programatically for all charts like from myCharts0 to myCharts21. Dont know the axact number of charts every times its differnent.

Comment: You probably want to dynamically manage the creation of your canvas nodes and hold onto a reference of those, instead of having the `*ngFor` in your template. This will allow you to keep track of the charts and dynamically manage them.

Comment: I achieved this by iterating on each chart in charts array and destroying one by one. this.charts.foreach(p => {p.destroy();})

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself by creating charts directly into charts array.

```
 var ctx4: any = document.getElementById(`chart` + i);
    this.charts.push(new Chart(ctx4, bar));
```

and destroyed the charts by iterating on charts array.

```
if (this.charts) {
      this.charts.forEach(p => {
        p.destroy();
      });
    }
```